# Returning pointers properly

Tags: c, pointers

I have created an ADT in C. It’s basically a linked list where. Each node in the list has a member variable that stores an item.

```
void *item
```

I have a member function for adding to the list and removing as well as others.

In my main.c file I call the ListAdd() function that takes a list and adds an item to the next available node. The ListFirst() function goes to the front of the list and returns the item stored at that node.

```
return list->item
```

My main function is storing a structure, that I have named pcb, as the item at each node. 
So here is my question. When I test the ADT the ListFirst() function, just before returning the void *item, has  all the correct member data of the item. But in my main.c file all the information is incorrect. Does anyone know why this could happen?

I thought since the item is a void * I am returning the address to the item. So in my main.c file the code looks like this:

```
typdef struct PCB{
        //member variables 
}pcb;

pcb *readypcb;
readypcb = (pcb *)ListFirst(listHead);
//print out data
```

So I thought that the readypcb pointer would point to the address of the item ListFirst() returns. Also I cast the return value to `(pcb *)` cause I return a `void *`.

So as a summary, the line right before I return the void *item prints out the item member data correctly. Then right after it’s asssigned to readypcb I print out the data again, only this time it’s all incorrect. Does anyone know what’s going on?

Here is some extra code that you guys are asking for:

The header file for my PCB data structure:

```
typedef enum Priority{

    high,
    medium,
    low

}Priority;

typedef enum State{

    running,
    ready,
    blocked
}State;

typedef struct PCB{

    Priority priority;              //records the priority level of the PCB
    int pid;                    //The process id of the control block
    State state;                    //records the state of the PCB

    char received[200];             //records any messads sent to this PCB
    char replied[200];              //records the messages that another process replies with

}pcb;
```

Then my main.c file where I assign the returned item:

```
int checkForReadyProcesses(listPtr highP, listPtr medP, listPtr lowP, pcb *readypcb){
    int retCode = 0;

    //check that the item counts for the ready queues are 0
    if(highP->itemCount > 0){
         readypcb = (pcb *)ListFirst(highP);
        //ListRemove(highP);

        if(TESTING_READY_QUEUES){
            printf("We have a PCB in the high priority queue\n");
        }

    }else if(medP->itemCount > 0){
        readypcb = (pcb *)ListFirst(medP);
        //ListRemove(medP);

        if(TESTING_READY_QUEUES){
            printf("We have a PCB in the medium priority queue\n");
        }

    }else if(lowP->itemCount > 0){
        readypcb = (pcb *)ListFirst(lowP);
        //ListRemove(lowP);

        if(TESTING_READY_QUEUES){
            printf("We have a PCB in the low priority queue\n");
        }

    }else{
        retCode = 1;
    }

    if(TESTING_READYPCB){
        printf("The ready address is: %p\n", readypcb);
        printf("The ready state is: %d\n", readypcb->state);
        printf("The ready priority is: %d\n", readypcb->priority);
        printf("The ready id is: %d\n", readypcb->pid);
    }

    return retCode;

}
```

Finally LstFirst():

```
void *ListFirst(LIST *list){
    void *tempItem;

    list->currentItem = list->firstNode->item;
    list->currentNode = list->firstNode;

    //updates the position
    list->position = first;

    tempItem = ((list->firstNode->item));

    pcb curpcb = *(pcb *)list->firstNode->item;

    printf("the item has the adress: %p\n", list->firstNode->item);
    printf("the item pid is: %d\n", curpcb.pid);
    printf("the item state is: %d\n", curpcb.state);
    printf("the item priority is: %d\n", curpcb.priority);

    return list->firstNode->item;
}
```

The List.h file:

```
typedef struct NODE *nodePtr;
typedef struct List *listPtr;

//define the node structire used for each node in the list except the head node
typedef struct NODE{    
    nodePtr nextNode;       //points to the next node in the list
    nodePtr previousNode;       //points to the previous node in the list
    void *item;         //holds the item for the node
} node;

//define the head structure for the List
typedef struct List{

    nodePtr firstNode;      //points to the first node of the list
    int itemCount;          //holds the number of items in the list
    nodePtr end;            //points to the end of the list
    void *currentItem;      //points to the current item
    nodePtr currentNode;        //points to the current node
    listPtr freedHeadNode;      //used for pointing to freedHead nodes when more than one is available

    //using an enum to represent where the current node is
    enum currentPos{
        beyondEnd = 2,
        end = 1,
        middle = 0,
        beforeStart = -1,
        first = -2,     //this represents the first item ever to be added
    } position;
} LIST;

//FUNCTIONS
LIST *ListCreate();         //creates a new list when called
int ListCount(LIST *list);      //returns the number of items in the list
void *ListFirst(LIST *list);        //returns the first item in the list
void *ListLast(LIST *list);     //returns a pointer to the last item
int ListAdd(LIST *list, void *item);    //adds an item to a list
void *ListCurr(LIST *list);     //points to the current item in the list
void *ListNext(LIST *list);     //points to the next item after the current spot
void *ListPrev(LIST *list);     //points to the previous item before the current node
int ListInsert(LIST *list, void *item); //inserts a node just before the previous node
int ListPrepend(LIST *list, void *item);//adds an item to the begining of the list
int ListAppend(LIST *list, void *item); //adds an item to the end of the list
void *ListRemove(LIST *list);       //removes and returns the current item from the list
void *ListTrim(LIST *list);     //returns and removes the last item of the list
void *ListSearch(LIST *list, int(*comparator)(void *, int), int comparatorArg);
void ListFree(LIST *list, void(itemFree)(void *));
```

I think that should help. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Can you post enough code so that we can test it? For example the ListFirst function and how you allocate those PCBs.

Comment: There is not enough code, please [edit] your question and show all relevant code.

Comment: We need to see the code for `ListFirst`, all related data structures and also the code that prints out the data.

Comment: Okay so I added some more of the code. I also posted all the function headers from my ADT implementation file. That way if you guys need to see one of them you know what I called it and then I can grab it for you guys and post it

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not see all your declarations, it is most likely that you pass the listhead, the head gets updated, but cannot be returned. The reason it cannot be returned is because you do not pass a "double pointer". Consider:

```
void example(list *head) {
    if (head==NULL) head= malloc(sizeof(list));
    //...
```

Here you allocate memory to `head` but `head` is a *local* variable; any changes to it cannot be seen by the caller. Instead, do:

```
void example(list **head) {
    if (*head==NULL) *head= malloc(sizeof(list));
    //...
```

and call like:

```
list *myList;
example(&myList);
```